# Decrypt home directory using mount pasphrase - files still encrypted

Tags: encryption, home-directory, ecryptfs, decryption

I am trying to recover data from an Ubuntu installation with an encrypted home directory mounted on a separate partition `/dev/sda1`. I don't have the login passphrase, but I do have the original mount passphrase.

I have tried recovering the data with an Ubuntu 16.04 live USB stick using:

```
sudo ecryptfs-recover-private media/ubuntu/home_partition/user/.ecryptfs/user/.Private
```

When asked if I know my login passphrase I say no and then enter the mount passphrase when prompted.

It seems to be working, the output is:

> INFO: Success! Private data mounted at [/tmp/encryptfs.xxxxxx].

However, when navigating to `/tmp/encryptfs.xxxxxx`, with nautilus as root, all I see is encrypted directories shown as `ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx`.

How can I actually decrypt and access my files?

Thank you!